# Mongoose: is pre save hook of parent always executed before pre-save hook of embedded documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As the title says: 
is the pre-save hook of the parent document always executed before the pre-save hook of embedded documents?

And if not, is there any hack to enforce it?

Use case: 
In the pre-save hook of the embedded documents I store some calculated fields to the parent.

In the pre-save hook of the parent I do something with that :)

**EDIT**

I'm asking because with the async-nature (?) of these hooks testing a couple of instances might not answer my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some testing: it looks like it is.